# Define class which returns passed argument with its own types

Tags: typescript

I need to create new class with 2 arguments. One of them can be different type each time I create new class.

```
class Some{
    constructor(type:string, data?){
        this.type = type;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

And in my IDE I want to see what is typeof `data` for each `Some` instance, because it could be `number`, `string` or `object` with custom keys.

I was trying to do something like this: `type IType<T> = T` but still, I do not know then how to get `T` inside my class and when I return `IType data` it just not works.

And sorry, maybe it is not possible or just trivial but I am not good at TypeScript yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Some<T>{
    constructor(
        private type: string,
        public data: T
    ) {
    }

    foo() {
        console.log(`my type is ${this.type} and my data is ${this.data}`)
    }
}

const bar = new Some('hello', 123);
bar.data; // Hover over me to see type in your IDE
bar.foo();
```